# IBM_DB installation error

Tags: python

I'm trying to install ibm_db in my python 3.5.2 in Anaconda 4.2 under Windows 7. I used following command `pip install "ibm-db==2.0.8a"` But I got installation error given in screen shot. Please suggest how to install ibm_db

[image]

Comment: You need to run pip as Administrator.

Comment: Please post errors and other text as text, not images